# HBase PrivilegedExceptionAction runAs thread?

Tags: java, thread-safety, hbase

I have HBase code that I use for gets (Although I don't have Kerberos on, I plan to have it later so I wanted to make sure that user credentials were handled correctly when connecting and doing a Put or Get).

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MyHBaseService.getUserHBase().runAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object run() throws Exception {
                    Connection connection = null;
                    Table StorageTable = null;
                    List<hFile> HbaseDownload = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        // Open an HBase Connection
                        connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(MyHBaseService.getHBaseConfiguration());
                     Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("filenameCell"));
                     Result result = table.get(get);
                     byte[] data = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(MyHBaseService.getDataStoreFamily()), Bytes.toBytes(MyHBaseService.getDataStoreQualifier()));
                     bos.write(data, 0, data.length);
                     bos.flush();
                     ...
                }
          });
          // now get the outputstream.
          // I am assuming byteArrayStream is synchronized and thread-safe.
          return bos.toByteArray();
```

However, I wasn't sure if this was running an asynchronous or synchronous thread.

The problem:

I use:

```
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("filenameCell"));
                Result result = table.get(get);
```

Inside this `run()` function. But to get information OUT of the `run()` thread I use a `new ByteOutputArrayStream` OUTSIDE the `run()`. `ByteOutputArrayStream.write` & `ByteOutputArrayStream.flush` inside the `run()`. Then `toByteArray()` to get the binary bytes of the `HBase` content out of the function. This causes null bytes to be returned though, so maybe I'm not doing this right.

However, I am having difficulty finding good examples of `HBase` Java API to do these things and no one seems to use runAs like I do. It's so strange.

I have HBase 1.2.5 client running inside a Web App (request-based function calls).

Answer (score 1):

Here in this code the thread is running inside "**MyHBaseService.getUserHBase().runAs**" this. But if it is running asyncronously then before executing it properly program will return **"bos.toByteArray();"** as this is outside the runAs(). So before even executing the complete function it will return the output.

I think thats the reason of null values.

Comment: But that's my point.... is it running asynchronously or synchronously I am extremely disappointed in the lack of documentation for HBase API. Even the HBase book is incomplete and lacks examples like this.